# Accessing OpportunityLineItem ProductCode field

Tags: apex, opportunity-lineitem

Currently I'm having issue saving my code:

```
public static void myMethodMyMethod(Map<Id,OpportunityLineItem> OLIs, String action){

        for(OpportunityLineItem oli:OLIs.values()){
            system.debug('oli.ProductCode '  + oli.ProductCode);
        }

}
```

I keep getting this error: Invalid field ProductCode for SObject OpportunityLineItem

I was able to print out other fields information from sObject oli (i.e. OpportunityId, UnitPrice, etc). For some reason ProductCode does not work...

Any advice?

Thank you,
Eric

Comment: 1) Check your API version of the class 2) Can you try oli.product2.productcode. As per docs https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm ProductCode :This read-only field is available in API version 30.0 and later. It references the value in the ProductCode field of the related Product2 record.

Comment: Yes! this is the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Check your API version of the class

2) Can you try oli.product2.productcode.

As per docs

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm

> ProductCode :This read-only field is available in API version 30.0 and
>   later. It references the value in the ProductCode field of the related
>   Product2 record